# is it possible to profile an adobe AIR for android/iOS application running on the device?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, flash-builder

I've experienced several intermittent system crashes on my Samsung Nexus S phone running Android ICS 4.0 while attempting to test/debug my AIR application on-device (*I am using AIR for Android version 3.3.0.365*); the [standard debug testing](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WSe4e4b720da9dedb5-6caff02f136a645e895-7fff.html) for mobile apps from Flash Builder 4.7 doesn't show any errors, nor does my device's `logcat` (other than to identify Adobe AIR [with my app running] as the cause of the crash).

Given that the problem is intermittent and doesn't seem to correspond to any specific set of events, I'd really like to use the profiler in Flash Builder 4.7 while the app is running on a device in order to get a full readout of what is going on.

I've already profiled the app on my desktop and found no obvious potential causes for crashes on Android, so now I'm wondering the following: is it possible to configure the Flash Builder 4.7 profiler to analyze an application while it is running on a mobile device connected via USB debugging?

Comment: I don't think that's possible with the current version of FB, so you might wanna file a feature request for FB 4.8. That feature would indeed be quite valuable.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, you can set a debug IP in one of the config files. If you fill in the local IP of the machine you are building the app on, you will be able to use a profiler via the wifi network. I'm not sure it works this way in flash builder though, I used flashdevelop.